# Can you position 2 containers with 'absolute' and still make it responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a website have two containers that stay the same size depending on the viewport size. One is the navbar and one is where the content will go. I am using 'absolute' positioning so that I can keep the containers a specific size no matter the size of content inside of them. Basically I want the site to never scroll and just be the 2 containers. (Mainly for desktop view, I will change the sites look once it gets down to mobile sizes)

Here is what I am trying so far:

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav-container {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        padding: 20px;
        
        position: absolute;
        height: 80%; 
        width: 20%; 
        top: 10%; 
        left: 10%;
    }
    
.content-container {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        padding: 20px;
        
        position: absolute;
        height: 80%; 
        width: 50%; 
        top: 10%;
        left: 38%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <h2>Navbar</h2>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
  <h2>Content</h2>
</div>
```

It's the basic concept of what I want it to be, but it's rough and doesn't really work with being responsive as it goes off the screen and creates a scrollbar. Is there a better way I could handle this? Can I somehow make the containers a 'block' format while using 'absolute' so they stack next to each other and I can separate with margin?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you are looking for?
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/XELRLr

I added the following CSS:

```
.nav-container,
.content-container{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The `overflow-y:scroll;` property will add a scroll bar when the nav or main content overflows its container, and `box-sizing:border-box;` will ensure that padding and border are included when calculating the size of the containers.

Good luck!